# Import Site Error

Tags: export, import

i'm trying to create a SharePoint Server for test and development exactly same as the prod one.

So my server is ok, as my db and my central admin.

Then I Created a new site collection on the TEST SERVER.

Then I performed a granular backup from central admin IN PROD (Export a site or List).

Then I went back to the Test server and by using SharePoint Management Shell
I typed the following command:

```
Import-SPWeb mysiteURL –Path mybackupfile.cmp -IncludeUserSecurity"
```

after a few minutes i get this message:
[image]

Comment: Seems you are missing a solution installed in production on your test server (containing the TswaWebParts feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are missing a solution installed in production on your test server (containing the TswaWebParts feature).

Take a look in Central admin for any differences in the installed solutions under System Settings->Manage Farm Solutions

Probably there is one in production that is not installed in your test environment. So you need to install that one before you can import your web

To download a farm solution you can use these lines of PowerShell in the SharePoint Management Shell on your production server:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("extendeddiagnosticproviders.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\temp\extendeddiagnosticproviders.wsp")
```

changing the name of the .wsp ofcource. [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/12/05/extract-a-wsp-solution-from-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Yes it seems there are all the solutions missing...
^^
is it possible to backup and restore them also?

Comment: This blogpost details what steps you can take to export SharePoint Solutions to a new farm: http://msmvps.com/blogs/shane/archive/2011/05/05/using-powershell-to-export-all-solutions-from-your-sharepoint-2010-farm-and-other-fun.aspx

Comment: i succeeded to export them but deploy on the other farm is not possible i get an error
"Failed to load receiver assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"
 i think i'm going to give up

Comment: it's ok i installed them with powershell with success

Comment: If this was the solution, feel free to mark as answer

Comment: yes the import worked fine (left it import all the weekend ^^) thanks